# Why would SQL server return double the line feeds for a string?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a .NET 4.0 website, where there is some text on the login page and home page stored in SQL Server 2008.  There's a page in the site to edit both of these texts.

When I click the link to edit, they display fine in a multiline textbox.  However, all line feeds are doubled when the stored procedure retrieves them from the database.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_WEB_getSiteConfig]
AS
    SELECT login_text, home_text FROM WEB_Site_Config
    RETURN
```

Text area contains:

> RHIOTest Home Page Text
>
> RHIOTest Home Page Text Line 2

Displayed on home page:

```
RHIOTest Home Page Text



RHIOTest Home Page Text Line 2
```

Comment: Did you actually look what content the table row contains? Was the text entered from the same browser/OS as you display it in?

Comment: Asp markup for part of the home page displaying those texts and the exact HTML generated could be helpful.

Comment: The behavior is the same regardless of Chrome or IE.  The ASP markup is `<tr height="300">
        <td class="LeftNavSection" width="10">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="LeftNavSection">
         <br>
         <asp:Label id="lblHomeMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label><br>
        </td>
        <td class="LeftNavSection" width="10">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>`

Comment: HTML: `<tr height="300">
        <td class="LeftNavSection" width="10">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="LeftNavSection">
         <br>
         <span id="lblHomeMessage">RHIOTest Home Page Text<br />&nbsp;<br /><br />&nbsp;<br /><br />&nbsp;<br />RHIOTest Home Page Text Line 2</span><br>
        </td>
        <td class="LeftNavSection" width="10">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>`

Comment: To the naked eye the actual table row content appears to have 6 spaces between the lines...  of course that's not what's actually there.  Is there a better way to see what special characters SQL server is storing?

Comment: You can copy the contents over to a Text file or do this: `Right click in the query window -> Results To -> Results To Text`

Comment: Thanks.  Results to Text shows that the strings are storing correctly.  It's something in the rendering that is spacing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was lines like these:

```
lblLoginMessage.Text = login_text.Replace ("\r\n", "<br />&nbsp;<br />");
```

What I don't understand is how this has been in production all this time without the customer reporting the problem...